# Fragment with ViewPager having blank pages after returning to it from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, kotlin, fragmentmanager

In my application I'm trying to create 2 fragments with `ViewPager`s. The fragments have 3 tabs/pages each with `RecyclerView`s and they are supposed to be backed by a database, so I'm keeping them in a `List`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {    
    val fragments = listOf(SwipeFragment(), SwipeFragment())

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder, fragments[0]).commit()
        button1.setOnClickListener { 
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder, fragments[0]).commit()
        }
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder, fragments[1]).commit()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that after navigating away from the `SwipeFragment` and going back, the view seems empty. Then, if you navigate to e.g. the leftmost page, the rightmost one "appears" (when you go to it).
This results in the middle page staying empty. (the reason for it being that `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` keeps only the current page and 2 adjacent ones by default. The middle one doesn't get refreshed in a layout with 3 tabs - I tried it also with 5 tabs and I'm able to bring all of them back by going back and forth).

After some debugging I saw that the fragments that represent pages don't get removed from the `FragmentManager`, but the main `SwipeFragment` is. I can't get my head around how `FragmentManager` really works, even after reading almost all of the source code.

If I were able to somehow safely remove the fragments from the `FragmentManager`, it may work.
I've tried some techniques for saving state, but the framework does that automatically (which might actually be the cause of this problem).
I'm just a beginner in Android, so there's probably a better way to do this anyway. I'll leave the rest of the files here for reference.

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="button2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

**SwipeFragment.kt**

```
class SwipeFragment : Fragment() {

    // TODO: set up and keep the database here

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_swipe, container, false)
        view.tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(view.pager)
        view.pager.adapter = DummyPagerAdapter(activity.supportFragmentManager, index)

        return view
    }
}
```

---

**fragment_swipe.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test.SwipeFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

---

**ItemListFragment.kt**

```
class ItemListFragment() : Fragment() {

    // Or keep the database here?
    // Probably not the best idea though

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false)
        if (view is RecyclerView) {
            view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context)
            view.adapter = MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS)
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

---

**DummyPagerAdapter.kt**

```
class DummyPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager, val parentIndex: Int) :
        FragmentStatePagerAdapter(manager) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = ItemListFragment()
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence = "${ position + 1 }"
    override fun getCount(): Int = 3
}
```

---

And a basic implementation of `RecyclerView.Adapter` generated by Android Studio

**MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.kt**

```
class MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(val values: List<DummyItem>) : 
        RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    ...
}
```

**fragment_item_list.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="com.example.test.ItemListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="com.example.test.ItemListFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item" />
```

Comment: try setting offScreenPageLimit to 2 like `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` this is `java` code. write equivalent code in `kotlin`

Comment: @mohammed this would only make the matter worse as the pages wouldn't refresh at all

Comment: use `addOnPageChangeListener() on viewpager` and refresh the pages inside `onPageSelected()`

Comment: @mohammed what do you mean by refresh the pages? Somehow inflate the view again, or what?

Answer (score 8):

You should use `childFragmentManager` instead of `activity.supportFragmentManager` inside `SwipeFragment`.

```
view.pager.adapter = DummyPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager, index)
```

The difference between `getSupportFragmentManager()` and `getChildFragmentManager()` is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740445/what-is-difference-between-getsupportfragmentmanager-and-getchildfragmentmanag).

> Basically, the difference is that Fragment's now have their own internal FragmentManager that can handle Fragments. The child FragmentManager is the one that handles Fragments contained within only the Fragment that it was added to. The other FragmentManager is contained within the entire Activity.

Comment: That's also one of the things I tried when searching for an answer, but the application keeps crashing. Here's the [stack trace](https://pastebin.com/3eKjrH7z). The main `FragmentManager` tries getting the state from its saved fragment array for some reason I can't figure out how to circumvent.

Comment: @JakubDąbek Is it possible for you to use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747975/difference-between-fragmentpageradapter-and-fragmentstatepageradapter)? I don't really know the reason of that error but it seems that it is caused by using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Comment: FYR, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665709/using-fragmentstatepageadapter-to-retain-position-for-fragment-with-viewpager) seems to have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `childFragmentManager` didn't help. I think we can use a pattern "Observer" to update existing fragments of `ViewPager` with new data when return from another fragment.